# Filter out an object with arrays having specific ids on the basis of an existing collection - (Aggregate Framework)?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm having two objects,

```
const originTimeStamp = {
    chats: '2021-06-25T12:21:21.835+00:00',
    users: '2021-06-21T12:21:21.835+00:00',
    history: '2021-06-18T12:21:21.835+00:00'
}

const controlIds = {
    chats: ['1bfe','2bfs','3bhr'],
    users: ['6jkj'],
    history: ['8her'],
}
```

and a collection that typically have some logs related to user activities:

```
{
  controlId: '2bfs'
  createdAt: '2021-07-19T12:21:21.835+00:00'
},
{
  controlId: '6jkj'
  createdAt: '2021-06-18T12:21:21.835+00:00'
},
{
  controlId: '8her'
  createdAt: '2021-06-25T12:21:21.835+00:00'
},
```

What I basically want to do is to filter out the controlIds object in such a way that if the control id exists in the collection and If the origin time stamp of that section say for chats '2021-06-25T12:21:21.835+00:00' < '2021-07-19T12:21:21.835+00:00' (of id '2bfs' from collection ) we will remove that id from the object.

Expected Result:

```
const controlIds = {
    chats: ['1bfe','3bhr'],
    users: ['6jkj'],
    history: [],
}
```

Is there any way to achieve it with aggregation pipeline, right now i tried creating a flow but not able to do that? Here is the suggested flow i tried so far:

- $match the documents with a particular range of timestamps
- $project only the control_Id
- $group them using $push to get all documents in an array
- Assign this output to a variable and filter your object.

Comment: are they `originTimeStamp` and `controlIds` collections in database? not clear exactly.

Comment: No they aren't, they are actually fetched from somewhere else. @turivishal

Comment: We can consider them as static objects. I was thinking to prepare that object on the aggregation pipeline and then compare and post process it later.

Comment: its like you need to process external object in mongodb? you can do it in client side language.

Comment: @turivishal but there are comparisons which i have to with the db, eg, scanning for existing control id in db

Comment: you can do that in query and then do operation in client side to remove `controllerIds`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234419/discussion-between-ashish-bairwa-and-turivishal).